# Has anyone migrated a Spring Oauth2 authorization server written on top of spring-security-oauth to spring-security-authorization?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

We've currently running in production an Oauth2 authorization server which is built on top of spring-security-oauth, but since spring-security-oauth library is deprecated we were considering to move to spring-security-authorization framework(https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/overview.html).

However looks like the new spring-security-authorization has different Oauth2 classes, different endpoints, tables etc.. which makes the migration process almost impossible. At first glance looks like we have to drop the current project and start from the scratch which of course is not something we want.

Has anyone completed the migration? Is anyone in this position now where they need to move from the old/deprecated spring-security-oauth to spring-authorization-server? Is there a proper guideline on how to easily upgrade?